# How to stop tomcat from adding trailing slash

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I've got a strange requirement. I would want to stop tomcat from adding a trailing slash and redirecting the page with Http code 302.

I've a sprinmvc application. In my web.xml I've configured the dispatcher servlet wiith the below mapping.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I know if I change the url pattern to "/*" would work. But then I need to write servlet mapping for each of my jsp files inside different directories. Can you provide any solution to stop this redirection(http code 302) by keeping dispacther servlet url pattern as "/".

I know I can use apache rewrite rules, but I don't want to use this solution.

Thanks,
Guru